# How do I make a function that validates user input in C?

Tags: c, input, validation, scanf

I need to write a function for my 1st semester c assignment. If anyone could help me I've written all of the assignment i just need to validate user input.  This is what the teacher gave me... if this is not enough info i can post more

`double get_double(void)`  function must be used to validate the input for each expense 
and income. It will continuously prompt the user for a numeric value until it meets the 
conditions. The value must be numeric and greater or equal to 0.  If any character input 
precedes or follows the number the input is to be treated as invalid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

double get_expenses(double* pSchool, double* pLiving, double* pTransp, double* pOther); /* function prototype */
double get_income(double* pEmploy, double* pOther);                                     /* function prototype */
double display_report(double School, double Living, double Transp, double OtherExp, double Employ, double OtherInc);  /* function prototype */
char get_char(char* pRecalculate);   /* function prototype */
void clear_buffer(void);   /* function prototype */
double get_double(void);   /* function prototype */

main() {

double school, living, transp, otherExp;
double employ, otherInc;
char recalculate;
int counter = 1;



while (counter > 0){  
    printf("Student Budget Planner\n");
    printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
    printf("Input Set: %d\n\n", counter);             
    get_expenses(&school, &living, &transp, &otherExp);
    get_income(&employ, &otherInc);
    display_report(school, living, transp, otherExp, employ, otherInc);
    clear_buffer();
    get_char(&recalculate);
     if (recalculate == 'Y' || recalculate == 'y'){
     counter = counter + 1;
        } else {
               counter = 0;
               }

}                                      
return 0;
}


double get_expenses(double* pSchool, double* pLiving, double* pTransp, double* pOther) {
*pSchool = *pLiving = *pTransp = *pOther = 0;

double tuition, textbooks, supplies, rent, utilities, phone, groceries;
double entertainment, transportation, car, insurance, gas, other;

printf("School Expenses:\n");
printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
printf("Tuition (per semester): ");
scanf("%lf", &tuition);
printf("\nTextbooks(per semester): ");
scanf("%lf", &textbooks);
printf("\nSupplies: ");
scanf("%lf", &supplies);

*pSchool = (tuition / 4) + (textbooks / 4) + supplies;

printf("\n\nLiving Expenses:\n");
printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
printf("Residence/Rent/Mortgage: ");
scanf("%lf", &rent);
printf("\nUtilities: ");  
scanf("%lf", &utilities);           
printf("\nPhone/Internet: "); 
scanf("%lf", &phone);                
printf("\nGroceries/Eating out: ");
scanf("%lf", &groceries);                 
printf("\nEntertainment: "); 
scanf("%lf", &entertainment);

*pLiving = rent + utilities + phone + groceries + entertainment;

printf("\n\nTransportation: \n");              
printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
printf("Public Transportation: "); 
scanf("%lf", &transportation);
printf("\nCar: ");
scanf("%lf", &car);
printf("\nAuto Insurance: ");
scanf("%lf", &insurance);
printf("\nGas/Maintenance: ");
scanf("%lf", &gas);

*pTransp = transportation + car + insurance + gas;

printf("\n\nOther: \n");
printf("~~~~~\n");
printf("Any other expenses: ");
scanf("%lf", &other);

*pOther = other;

return *pSchool, *pLiving, *pTransp, *pOther;
}

double get_income(double* pEmploy, double* pOther){
*pEmploy = *pOther = 0;

double wages, family, scholarship, other;

printf("\n\nEmployment income:\n");
printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
printf("Expected Wages/Tips: ");
scanf("%lf", &wages);

*pEmploy = wages;

printf("\n\nOther income:\n");
printf("~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
printf("Family Support: ");
scanf("%lf", &family);
printf("\nScholarship/Bursaries (per semester): ");
scanf("%lf", &scholarship);
printf("\nOther: ");
scanf("%lf", &other);

*pOther = family + scholarship + other;

return *pEmploy, *pOther;
}

double display_report(double School, double Living, double Transp, double OtherExp, double Employ, double OtherInc) {  

printf("\n\nStudent Name Budget Report\n");  
printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
printf("Expenses:\n");
printf("~~~~~~~~\n");
printf("                                              MONTHLY  ANNUALY\n");
printf("School Expenses:                              $%.2lf   $%.2lf\n", School, School * 12);
printf("Living Expenses:                              $%.2lf   $%.2lf\n", Living, Living * 12);
printf("Transportation Expenses:                      $%.2lf   $%.2lf\n", Transp, Transp * 12);
printf("Other Expenses:                               $%.2lf   $%.2lf\n", OtherExp, OtherExp * 12);
printf("total Expenses:                               $%.2lf   $%.2lf\n", School + Living + Transp + OtherExp, School * 12 + Living * 12 + Transp * 12 + OtherExp * 12); 
printf("Income:\n");
printf("~~~~~~~\n");
printf("Employment Income:                            $%.2lf   $%.2lf\n", Employ, Employ * 12);
printf("Other Income:                                 $%.2lf   $%.2lf\n", OtherInc, OtherInc * 12);
printf("Total Income:                                 $%.2lf   $%.2lf\n", Employ + OtherInc, Employ * 12 + OtherInc * 12);
printf("Total Savings Available for your Goals:       $%.2lf   $%.2lf\n", (Employ + OtherInc) - (School + Living + Transp + OtherExp), (Employ * 12 + OtherInc * 12)- (School * 12 + Living * 12 + Transp * 12 + OtherExp * 12));


return 0;
}

char get_char(char* pRecalculate){

     int valid_input;

     valid_input = 0;

     while (valid_input == 0){
     printf("\nWould you like to recalculate your budget? (Y/N): ");
     scanf("%c", &*pRecalculate);
     *pRecalculate = toupper(*pRecalculate);
     if (*pRecalculate == 'Y' || *pRecalculate == 'y' || *pRecalculate == 'N' || *pRecalculate == 'n') valid_input = 1;
         else printf("Error Invalid choice\n");


     printf("\n");
     }

     return *pRecalculate;
     }


void clear_buffer(void) {

while ( getchar() != '\n' );
}

double get_double()
{

 // What to put here?
}
```

Comment: @azuyer: You've got to post some code. Show your work.
And I suggest do it as soon as you can or people will down vote the heck out or post.

Comment: [How to Ask and Answer Homework Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: i tried posting everything but it says there was a formatting error or somethin

Comment: double get_expenses(double* pSchool, double* pLiving, double* pTransp, double* pOther); /* function prototype */
double get_income(double* pEmploy, double* pOther);                                     /* function prototype */
double display_report(double School, double Living, double Transp, double OtherExp, double Employ, double OtherInc);  /* function prototype */
char get_char(char* pRecalculate);   /* function prototype */
void clear_buffer(void);   /* function prototype */
double get_double(void);   /* function prototype */

Comment: +1 for actually making an effort to fix your question. Most new users rage-quit after seeing the initial flood of downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Think about the train of process, and think about the flowchart/decision tree you want your program or function to follow.

You don't want to stop asking the user for input until valid input has been entered. You are guaranteed to ask the user at least once, but might ask multiple times. The input is either valid or invalid.

Now we begin to draft some pseudo-code. Here's how I would do it:

```
double get_double(void)
{
    double d;
    int ask_again = 1; /* continue if 1 (true), exit if 0 (false) */

    do {
        /* display message to user to let them know to type a number */
        /* read user input */
        if (/* user input didn't input a valid double */)
        {
            /* display appropriate error message */
        }
        else if (/* user entered a double, but it wasn't greater than or equal to zero */)
        {
            /* display appropriate error message */
        }
        else    /* user entered valid input, so ...  */
        {
            /* ... do something to make sure the loop exists */
        }
    } while (/* we need to ask again */);
}
```

This yells do-while to me, so I wrote it in a do-while loop. I provided an `int ask_again` variable, but I leave it to you where it might be useful, if at all.

You should consider what real code should go where all the comments are.
Check with your course notes to see what techniques your teacher expects you to know to apply here.

Reading and sanitizing user-input is a notorious problem in all computer languages, especially C. StackOverflow can give you ideas of how you might perform a particular action.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
double get_double()
{
    double d;

    if (scanf("%lf", &d) != 1)
        /* handle error */
        reurn -1;

    if (d < 0)
        /* handle error */
        return -1;

    return d;
}
```

Or, as Keith Thompson pointed out, you can also be safe:

```
double get_double()
{
    double d;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len;

    getline(&line, &len, stdin);
    if (line == NULL)
        return -1;

    d = strtod(line, NULL);
    free(line);

    if (d < 0)
        /* handle error */
        return -1;

    return d;
}
```

You can use it like this (as there's no way to return all the entered doubles in one single double -- maybe you want an array, but the question specified the target signature as double (*)()):

```
double d;

while ((d = get_double()) >= 0)
{
    /* do what you want */
}
```

Comment: `scanf` has undefined behavior if the input value is outside the range of the target type (`double` in this case); see [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.21.6.2p10

Comment: The question says *It will continuously prompt the user for a numeric value until it meets the conditions. The value must be numeric and greater or equal to 0. If any character input precedes or follows the number the input is to be treated as invalid.*

Comment: @KeithThompson so what's the problem here?

Comment: When the call `scanf("%lf", &d)` is executed, if the user enters, for example, `1.0e1000000`, the behavior is undefined; there's no guarantee `scanf` will indicate an error. It could crash the program. (Oh, and you mispelled `return` on the following line.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks! I'll update. But this essentially neans we can't use `scanf()`?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what it means, at least for numeric input. Unless you're willing to depend on the behavior of a particular implementation. In practice, I think most implementations behave reasonably. A more bulletproof solution is to use `fgets()` and `strtol()`.

Comment: @KeithThompson now you're satisfied, are you?

Comment: `getline` is not standard (or is it POSIX?) From the way the call looks, I presume it allocates memory; you never free it.